# Bad Gateway The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server- Azure Server

Tags: apache, tomcat, azure, timeout

I am getting the following error, while accessing the site hosted in **Microsoft Azure Virtual Server** after waiting for few minutes.

```
502 Bad Gateway The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
```

**The most confusing part is that, if we refresh the page, it works perfectly fine and loads very fast**

The following is the configuration:

```
OS: Windows Server 2012, VC 14

Webserver: Apache: 2.4.12

Tomcat: 8.0.23

Connector: Mod_JK 1.2.40
```

apache workers conf:

```
worker.list=worker1
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8009
```

The following is the lines from the log:

```
[Mon Jul 20 08:21:05 2015][2640:996] [info] ajp_connection_tcp_get_message::jk_ajp_common.c (1291): (w_tc) can't receive the response header message from tomcat, network problems or tomcat (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8009) is down (errno=60)

[Mon Jul 20 08:21:05 2015][2640:996] [error] ajp_get_reply::jk_ajp_common.c (2176): (w_tc) Tomcat is down or refused connection. No response has been sent to the client (yet)

[Mon Jul 20 08:21:05 2015][2640:996] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2673): (w_tc) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable),  (attempt=1)
```

Please refer the error page:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try to do :

```
$> killall -9 httpd
$> rm -f /var/lock/subsys/httpd
$> service httpd restart
```

If the above is not fixing then try the following. Comment out the following module in your `httpd.conf` and restart the Apache server.

```
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
```

Then:

```
$> restart http server
$> /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```